# How to send data to the parent page again on the close of child component pop up page in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, parent-child

I am trying to achieve following :

1. On Parent page on click of Button Child Component opens which is a
   popup
2. After saving data on child popup component I need to pass the data
   from Child component to Parent.
3. I am using Emit() to pass the data which is working on ngOnInit() but not on click of save button in Child component.

Parent Component HTML-

```
<parentComponent>
 <app-upsert-service-pop-up *ngIf="this.AddService [childProperty]="this.parentProperty"
  (onInitEvent)="receiveAutoMsgHandler($event)"
  (savedService)="serviceChangedHandler($event)">
 </app-upsert-service-pop-up>
</parentComponent>
```

TS-

```
 serviceChangedHandler(data: any) {
    console.log("Data from CHild component--");
    this.childServiceDataChange  = data;
    console.log("Data from CHild component--",data);
  }
  receiveAutoMsgHandler(p) {
    this.msgOnChildCompInit = p;
    console.log(p);
  }
```

CHILD-

```
@Output() savedService =new EventEmitter();
 @Output() onInitEvent = new EventEmitter();
 ngOnInit() {
    this.onInitEvent.emit('This meesage is appeared automatically as the child component 
    will intialized. This message is defined in the child component ngOninit method');}
 onSaveServerDetails() {
    this.savedService.emit('After saving data');}
```

onInitEvent- is working but similar code for savedServices is not working.

and i am not sure why, is it beacuse the child component is a pop or am i missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

The pattern that I've usually used and seen elsewhere is to have the "parent" page pass a callback to the dialog component.

Then when the dialog's 'submit' button is clicked, the dialog calls the parent's callback, sending the data as a parameter, before it closes itself.